# Android Library - Include used 3rd party libraries to .aar

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-library

I'm building an android library. However, when I package the library and add it to a project, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for some of the 3rd party libraries I use in the library. I want to add the 3rd party libraries I use for this into the library package (.aar), how can I do this?